# I can't uninstall the Webform module

Tags: webforms

I have the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/releases/8.x-5.0-beta9) module version  8.x-5.0-beta9, and when I try to uninstall the module Drush asks me to uninstall the webform_demo_application_evaluation module, first. When I try
`drush pm-uninstall webform_demo_application_evaluation`, it throws an error.

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function `getColumns()` on boolean in
>   /var/www-drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php on
>   line 227
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   Error: Call to a member function getColumns() on boolean in /var/www-drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php, line 227

How do I resolve this issue? Do I need to install the development snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to manually delete the demo forms, blocks, and nodes and then uninstall the demo module.

Please create a ticket in the [Webform issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform).

Comment: I manually deleted **webform_demo** and **webform_node** inside modules folder and then i could uninstall the **webform** using drush . Thanks .